# generic path for arbitrary model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my step-definition, I want to create a path to a named route for an arbitrary Model, like so:

```
Given(/^a new "(.*?)" form$/) do |model|
  path = send("new_admin_#{model.downcase}_path".to_sym)
  visit path
end
```

Used as

```
Given a new "Image" form
Given a new "User" form
```

I recall using a helper method in the past for this, one that allowed me to pass a modelname and some additional options, like the action and object or IDs. But I cannot find that anymore. This is for Rails 3.2.x.

Is there such a "magic" helper? If so, what is it? If not, are there common patterns to create paths to arbitrary Models?

Comment: Is the "magic" helper you are referring to activated by putting resources :images in your config/routes.rb file?

Comment: Sortof. `resources :images` is in the routes, but trough `ActiveAdmin`. But that matters little. It could just as well be `new_#{model.downcase}_path` or even `#{model.downcase}_path`.